# International InternedAddress in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, email-validation

I have a problem. I'm using java class javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress to parse and send email via SMTP and I can't change class (should use it). The problem is that I want to allow users insert international email addresses (with local symbols), which is consistent to RFC 6531 and RFC 6532. But java InternetAddress does not accept such emails.
Are there solutions of my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you already tried?

Comment: Nothing. I have no any ideas :D I can't use regex because I need that class

Comment: Show the code which you have, generally utf-8 should work.

Comment: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse-java.lang.String-boolean-) it doesn't work with local symbols such as ä, ö, ś etc. I'm using that method.

Comment: Have you tried setting strict to false?

Comment: yes. Sure. But it didn't help. Unfortunately

Comment: Like i said, without code, I cannot help you. post it or Good luck.

Comment: `import javax.mail.internet.*;  
InternetAddress email = new InternetAddress();  
System.out.println(email.parse("großer@gtdf.com", false));  `
    
will print: Local address contains control or whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code into this.

```
import javax.mail.internet.*; 

InternetAddress email = new InternetAddress();
System.out.println(email.parse("\"großer@gtdf.com\""));
```

Though this is pretty much a workaround for this case. I thing the only good solution would be wait for java team to update the `InternetAddress` class to be able to support international email address. As the current one only support [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Comment: If you're interested in testing a version of JavaMail 1.6.0 with this support, please contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Answer (score 2):

Java mail finally supports RFC 6531 and RFC 6532 with version 1.6

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4049399

If you are using maven ...

```
    <properties>
        <java.mail.version>1.6.1</java.mail.version>
    </properties>

...

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
                <version>${java.mail.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                <version>${java.mail.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```